# You are attempting to connect to Xero using TLS 1.0 which has been deprecated. Please use a newer TLS version

Tags: xero-api

I am using Xero in our system and it is .net application.
Before Up gradation of TLS version of Xero its working fine but after 30th June its not working.

Right now i am use Private application type of Xero.
I have download new open SSl certificate and also create new [public/private](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api-guides/create-publicprivate-key) key pair after up-gradation of Xero TLS.but still it's giving me

> The XeroAPI returned an ApiException response: You are attempting to
>   connect to Xero using TLS 1.0 which has been deprecated. Please use a
>   newer TLS version. Please Contact the API support team at api@xero.com
>   for more assistance.

Please any one help What will be changes or steps to do in my C# application for support new TLS and working my project.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you need to make some changes to your running application to allow it to run at the higher TLS version.

The information in the following couple of pull requests should provide some useful information.

- https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Net/issues/318
- https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Net/issues/329

Cheers,
Matt